# Staging Task Group display name looks like the code name after upgrading to Kentico 9

Tags: kentico

After upgrading to Kentico 9, we noticed that the UI elements (e.g. buttons, dropdown items) associated with Staging Task Groups appear to use the code name instead of the prettier display name:

[image: Staging Task Group Names]

I found [Kentico 10 documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/creating-custom-modules/reference-managing-ui-elements) that indicates these can be changed in the Modules app, under the "User interface" section. However, it says,

> Do NOT use the Customize option to edit the UI elements of the default
>   Kentico modules. The system may overwrite such changes when upgrading
>   or hotfixing to a newer version. Instead, add your own UI elements
>   under a custom module and then use the resulting interface instead of
>   the original.

It seems the display name should be used by default, so I am unsure how to remedy the situation. Also, there is the possibility that something went wrong during the upgrade, or a file is missing. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would check to see if something went wrong, or you missed the last step that gives a list of files it did not overwrite because it thought they were modified and instead put a .new on the new file until you can resolve.

First check your solution for any files ending in ".new" this issue would most likely be a resource file (.resx) didn't make it.

If you find the files with .new on it, check the non .new file next to it, copy over any custom stuff you did to the .new, then remove the old file and remove ".new" from the new file.

Comment: From what you say, it sounds like this isn't the correct behavior out of the box, correct?

Comment: I found a `~/CMS/CMSResources/CMS.resx.new` file. This was the culprit. Thanks!